# Hosting Asp.net web site with DataBase to hosting server

Tags: asp.net, sql, web, hosting, uploading

I have developed an e-comm web site in asp.net with sql server as a database.
Now I want to upload that web site with DB to hosting server.

This is my first web hosting and I don't know how to do it.

I've created the DB script to recreate the DB at the hosting server, but I don't know how to run it on server. Please tell me how to do this.

Please tell me what changes need to be done in my connection string in web.config file for connecting the DB which will be on hosting server.

My connection string is:

```
<add name="DBCS" connectionString="data source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;database=LAAFOOD;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I also have ftp client "Filezilla" which i am able to use for uploading static html pages on server.

Also tell me, are there any kind of free hosting services available for testing my E-comm web site online?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Your web host should have a way to setup a database and should tell you what the connection string is.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the connection string in web.config from your local db to the connection string for the remote db. Upload your web.config. Alternatively you can comment out the local string and just the remote connection string. That way you can switch as needed when testing locally.

You will also need to create the remote db too. You can use Sql Management studio to connect to the remote db and run the sql script to create the db.